# How to access the headers a HTTP response that you didn't send by AJAX using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web, client

I currently have a login page set up where it sends a HTTP post request to the server and then in a response message it redirects me to another page on the server. On that page I want to access the location header which contains a value that I need to perform future work with my server. Is there anyway to read that location header from the response so that I can get the value?

I know that you can access headers if you sent an ajax request by using the XMLHttpRequest object in the callback! But I am not using ajax so I cannot do that?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

No, that information is not available. For a complete explanation, see [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript).

Your best bet would be to have the server put the information somewhere on the new page where you can retrieve it, e.g. a hidden field.